# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-method-syntax

This query is being compiled without errors:

```
            var _entityList = context.customer

                .Join(context.applications,
                cust => cust.cust_id,
                app => app.cust_id,
                (cust, app) => new { customer = cust, application = app })

                .Join(context.advices,
                cust => cust.application.app_id,
                sa => sa.app_id,
                (cust, sa) => new { customer = cust, advice = sa })

                .GroupBy(g => new { g.customer.customer.cust_id, g.customer.customer.cust_code, g.customer.customer.cust_name })
                .Select(g => new { cust_id = g.Key.cust_id, cust_code = g.Key.cust_code, cust_name = g.Key.cust_name })
                .ToList();
```

While adding a conditional where clause to the above query returns compile time type conversion error:

```
            var _entityList = context.customer

                .Join(context.applications,
                cust => cust.cust_id,
                app => app.cust_id,
                (cust, app) => new { customer = cust, application = app })

                .Join(context.advices,
                cust => cust.application.app_id,
                sa => sa.app_id,
                (cust, sa) => new { customer = cust, advice = sa });

            if (custcode != null && custcode != "")
                _entityList = _entityList.Where(e => e.customer.customer.cust_code == custcode);

            _entityList = _entityList
                .GroupBy(g => new { g.customer.customer.cust_id, g.customer.customer.cust_code, g.customer.customer.cust_name })
                .Select(g => new { cust_id = g.Key.cust_id, cust_code = g.Key.cust_code, cust_name = g.Key.cust_name })
                .ToList(); // error on this line
```

**Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>` to `System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>`**

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that e.customer.customer.cust_code and custcode are both normal strings?

Comment: _entityListis of type IQueryable and you are trying to assign in List?

Comment: I would suggest you create a type class and uses it in your selects

Comment: @Ali.NET untill last `_entityList = _entityList`, `_entityList` is `IQueryable<Type1>`. With your last linq you create a new Type , create a list from it and try to assing the result to `IQueryable<Type1>`. (Like `IQueryable<Type1> = List<Type2>`)

Comment: @Marcus yes, both are normal strings. even if i comment out the conditional where, still returns compilation error.

Comment: @I4V sorry i didn't get you @ " ... create a list from it and try to assign ...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following simplified code sample:

```
var _entityList = Enumerable.Range(0, 1)
    .Select(i=>new {i1 =i, i2 = i+1});
_entityList = _entityList
    //.Select(i => new { i1 = i.i1, i2 = i.i2 })    // works
    //.Select(i => i)                               // works
    .Select(i => new { i })                         // fails
    .ToList();
```

In your first scenario, there is only one anonymous type involved, hence `_entityList` is a `List<AnonymousType#1>`. In your 2nd scenario, you change the returned type from one anonymous type:

```
new { 
    customer = cust, 
    advice = sa 
}
```

to another:

```
new { 
    cust_id = g.Key.cust_id, 
    cust_code = g.Key.cust_code, 
    cust_name = g.Key.cust_name 
}
```

so a conversion error occurs.

Try this:

```
var _entityList = context.customer
    .Join(context.applications,
            cust => cust.cust_id,
            app => app.cust_id,
            (cust, app) => new { customer = cust, application = app })
    .Join(context.advices,
            cust => cust.application.app_id,
            sa => sa.app_id,
            (cust, sa) => new { customer = cust, advice = sa })
    .Where(e => (custcode != null && custcode != "") 
        ? e.customer.customer.cust_code == custcode : true)
    .GroupBy(g => new { 
        g.customer.customer.cust_id, 
        g.customer.customer.cust_code, 
        g.customer.customer.cust_name })
    .Select(g => new { 
        cust_id = g.Key.cust_id, 
        cust_code = g.Key.cust_code, 
        cust_name = g.Key.cust_name })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: So how to workaround this issue? Your simplified sample seems just an illustration of the issue. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
_entityList = _entityList
            .GroupBy(g => new { g.customer.customer.cust_id, g.customer.customer.cust_code, g.customer.customer.cust_name })
            .Select(g => new { cust_id = g.Key.cust_id, cust_code = g.Key.cust_code, cust_name = g.Key.cust_name })
            .ToList(); // error on this line
```

to

```
var result = _entityList
            .GroupBy(g => new { g.customer.customer.cust_id, g.customer.customer.cust_code, g.customer.customer.cust_name })
            .Select(g => new { cust_id = g.Key.cust_id, cust_code = g.Key.cust_code, cust_name = g.Key.cust_name })
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you apply the When clause you use the type

```
(cust, sa) => new { customer = cust, advice = sa }.
```

But after you change to

```
new { cust_id = g.Key.cust_id, cust_code = g.Key.cust_code, cust_name = g.Key.cust_name }
```

They are different types to compiler.

Comment: It depends on what you want. Maybe apply the where just before ToList(). Something like this `.Where(e => e.cust_code == custcode)` I think could work.

Comment: It didn't work. In fact, it still returns error after removing the conditional where altogether. However, I have to try other suggestions now.