# using one list value in another list using anonymous types

Tags: linq, list

I have a list x with anonymous types in which i want to use a value which pre-calculated

```
int count1 = 
    (from users in dc.BeadSets 
     where users.UserId == i 
     select users
    ).Count();

 var x = 
    (from users in dc.Users 
     where users.Id == i 
     select  new { username = users.UserName
                 , fullname = users.FirstName + " " + users.LastName
                 , userid = users.Id 
                 }
    ).ToList();
```

Now this is working fine as usual

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>'
    to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#2>'
```

but while i am trying to use like this its throwing above error

```
int count1 = 
    (from users in dc.BeadSets 
     where users.UserId == i 
     select users
    ).Count();

x = 
    (from users in dc.Users 
     where users.Id == i 
     select  new { beadsets= count1
                 , username = users.UserName
                 , fullname = users.FirstName + " " + users.LastName
                 , userid = users.Id }
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Currently we don't know how your `x` variable is declared. Also, please reformat your code to avoid using horizontal scrolling when it's unnecessary.

Comment: I think he is declaring `x` just there ... I have prepared it a bit for you ;) (BTW: do you have some kind of C# watch-deamon or something?)

Comment: Based on the assumption that you re-assign `x` here in the way I tried to indicate in the reformated question you it should be rather clear why this cannot work! Just as an example: your first type of `x` has 3 fields - your second has 4!

Comment: @CarstenKönig yes thats the issue i guess. Thanks

Comment: I never tried so you might run into problems even if you have the same structure there (most likely I would say) - so just refactor it and introduce a lean struct/class for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249238/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-collections-generic-listanonymoustype1)